# Is there a way to check/repair a VirtualBox .vdi disk?

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, repair

I extended a disk with the command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd <absolute path to file> --resize <size in MB>
```

But now the disk is seen like empty, without even a partition, will not boot. I think it is corrupted in some way, is there a way to check/repair the virtual disk?

Comment: Just running any disk utility would work.

Comment: @Ramhound I am thinking maybe `VBoxManage` messed up the file in some way and not the disk space / partition

Comment: You do understand I was suggesting you running the disk utility from within the virtual machine right?  Verify if .vdi file has the correct header.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I understand that, but isn't there possibility that the .vdi file is no longer a valid disk file?

Comment: Which is the reason I asked if the header is correct.  You can use a hex editor of your choice and compared it to a disk that is working.  You can also tell in this process if your files exist or if its just random noise.

Comment: Maybe you want to make a backup, then try to expand again? Maybe this might help. Also if there's an error message.